# How to prove an inequality?

Tags: analysis, inequality

I got a problem when I try to prove this inequality:

$\left(a+\dfrac{2}{3}b\right)^{3/2}-\dfrac{2}{3}(a+b)^{3/2}>0$ always holds under $\dfrac{2}{3}a>b\ge0$

Does anyone have some ideas?

My attempts:

I got a way by taking derivative of $a$, but it seems true for all $a>b$.

Comment: @in zang It's wrong. Try $a=0$ and $b=-1$. I solved your problem for any $\frac{2}{3}a>b>0.$ If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Dear Michael, Thanks for your comment. But I really have no idea how to prove it. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Firstly, your problem is wrong. See my previous comment. Fix please your problem. Also, it's impossible, that you did not try something. Show it and you'll get a solution (hint) immediately.

Comment: Hi, Michael, I got a way by taking derivative of 'a', but it seems true for all 'a>b', is that your way? Please share with me your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

It's true for any $a>b\geq0.$

But your problem is also true.

Indeed, we need to prove that $$\left(a+\frac{2}{3}b\right)^3\geq\frac{4}{9}(a+b)^3$$ or
$$(3a+2b)^3\geq12(a+b)^3$$ or
$$15a^3+18a^2b-4b^3\geq0$$ or
$$15a^3+4b\left(\frac{9}{2}a^2-b^2\right)>0,$$ which is obvious for $\frac{2}{3}a>b\geq0.$

Comment: You are right. I thought this problem was complicated. Now I think I am stupid. Thanks a lot.